# Do any countries or states require citizens to pass a knowledge-based test before voting?

Tags: voting, political-theory, noocracy

In [Against Democracy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691162603), Georgetown University political philosopher Jason Brennan presents his case for [epistocracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noocracy).

Do any countries or states require citizens to pass a knowledge-based test before voting?

Although I'm interested in debating the merits of epistocracy, I'd like to know if any country actually employs a knowledge test.

Comment: [Literacy tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literacy_test#Voting) used to be used in America to some extent for voter registration (though the exemptions for almost all whites didn't lead to an epistocracy being formed)

Comment: Does anyone know if any country currently employs a knowledge test? I would support something very basic with questions like, "How many branches of government are there?" Very basic stuff anyone voting SHOULD know.

Comment: @user27343 I remember reading long time ago that some country had a system in which every adult could vote, but literate people are actually obliged to. Does it count and shall I look it up?

Comment: Comments deleted. As the question says, this is not a debate about epistocracy.

Comment: Related questions: [Issue-Specific Knowledge Tests For Voting](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11181/), [Vote amount according to “intelligence”](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11168), [Should the right to vote and/or be voted for be restricted to the educated in the information era?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10869/) and [What are some arguments for why a “license to vote” is a bad idea?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/20679/)

Comment: Snark: I always thought this would be a good idea for the USA, but it will never happen because our representatives themselves wouldn't pass such tests.

Comment: See also [my answer to a related question about requiring political representatives to pass a test](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/34427/7303).

Comment: Brazil and Ecuador - compulsory voting only for literate people: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compulsory_voting#Enforced

Answer (score 3):

In the Pre-Civil Rights Act South, several states implemented "voter literacy tests" which voters had to pass in order to be allowed to vote.

These test included reading some paragraph of law, writing out dictated phrases, and answering written questions about both civics and general topics.

In general these tests were really designed to be as confusing as possible for black people to deny them suffrage.

Take a look at some of these tests:
https://slate.com/human-interest/2013/06/voting-rights-and-the-supreme-court-the-impossible-literacy-test-louisiana-used-to-give-black-voters.html

https://www.crmvet.org/info/litques.htm

Comment: They were confusing for many white people as well, but there were always "grandfather clauses": if your grandfather had had the right to vote, you would have that right without a need of taking the test. Of course, the idea of such clause was that the grandfathers of black people would have been slaves and would have not have voting rights, while the grandfathers of white people would have had those rights.